# Url escape/unescape functions in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am looking for url escape and unescape functions in MonoTouch. Essentially I am looking for the MonoTouch equivalent of the method *stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding*, as in the follow line of objective-c code:

```
 NSString *args = [(NSString*)[components objectAtIndex:3]
                   stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I was expecting to be able to translate this to something like this:

```
string args = URL.Unescape(components[3]);
```

Do URL escape/unescape functions exist in MonoTouch or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode (string s);
```

Which is in System.Web.Services.dll in monotouch.

Comment: I don't see the namespace _HttpUtility_ under _System.Net_ in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Sorry meant System.Web.Services.dll

Comment: Yes, it is indeed there. I included _System.Web.Services.dll_ and now I do see it. Thanks, Geoff.

Comment: Note that MonoDevelop might automatically think you mean `System.Net.HttpUtility` and then complain that the class doesn't exist; so you need to prefix it with namespace (that is, write `System.Web.HttpUtility`) in order to avoid a compiler error.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Studio with Mono 3.0.10 and in there, you need to reference the System.Web dll and include it with

    using System.Web;

Then you will have the HTTPUtility and encode/decode functionality available.. btw: i'm using Xamarin.iOS Version: 6.3.4.36

Answer (score 1):

It is not present in the version of the .Net framework included with MonoTouch.

I believe I got the source for it off of Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/HttpUtility.cs?r=961).

You may want to look up the license for this, I used it for a personal iPhone app.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. That is great. From the message at the top of the code it seems that this code is open source. This is just what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: It most certainly is in monotouch, I know because I put it there, but I forgot we have a internal one in System.dll, the public one is in System.Web.Services.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer,
Split has params parameter Split('&','='); expression firstly split by & then '=' so odd elements are all values to be encoded shown below.

```
    public static void EncodedQueryString(ref string queryString)
    {
        var array=queryString.Split('&','=');
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
            string part=array[i];
            if(i%2==1)
            {               
                part=System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(array[i]);
                queryString=queryString.Replace(array[i],part);
            }
        }
    }
```

You should encode just the values generally.